# Laravel eloquent model - get rows using intermediate table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables users, posts and photos.

post table has one - one relation to photos & users like, `post.user_id=users.id` and `post_photo_id=photos._id`.

I use

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

and I get all the posts by user using $user->posts().

What I need is to get all the photos by user, something like $user->photos.

`SELECT photos.* 
FROM photos 
JOIN posts ON posts.photo_id=photos.id 
JOIN users ON users.id=posts.user_id 
WHERE user_id=1`

Note: photos table has just 2 fields, id & photo.

Comment: Try attaching a `->whereIn()` with a subquery, or do the join directly on the relation. A relation just returns a query object, and all query builder methods are present for use.

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, create a relationship like

```
Class User Extends Model
{
...
public function photos()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Photos','Posts','photo_id','id');
   // Params (all strings): Final Model, Intermediate Model, Intermediate Model Key (posts), final Model Key (your photos)  
}

public function Posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Posts');
}
...
}// end class
```

Then in your controller, you'll just call your data with the relationships. This assumes you're hinting, but you get the idea...

```
$picturesByUser = $this->user->with(['posts','photos'])->find($id);
```

finally, in your blade, just eager load them...

```
@foreach(...)
  $user->photos->pathToPicture;
  $user->posts->pictureTitle;
@endforeach
```

[Straight out of the Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: This (hasManyThrough) is only for Laravel 5.8*